# How to replace pandas data frame values using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

This is my old code it worked fine in pandas old version and now it's not working in the latest version of pandas.

````py
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame ([{"Type":"R_NEW","Status":"CHANGE","Email":"gra.com"},{"Type":"R_Change"," Status":"WAIT","Email":"rog.com"},{"Type":"Preorder","Status":"WAIT","Email":"dgrse.com"}])
    
    df.replace(to_replace={"R_New":"New","R_Change":"Change","R_DELETE":"Delete","Preorder":"Preorder"},value=None,inplace=True,regex=True)
    
    print(df)
    ```
        
    
    Expected output:
             
           Type  Status      Email  
    0     NEW  CHANGE    gra.com    
    1  Change     NaN    rog.com    
    2  Preorder    WAIT  dgrse.com    
        
      But I am getting:
           Type  Status      Email  
    0     R_NEW  CHANGE    gra.com    
    1  R_Change     NaN    rog.com   
    2  Preorder    WAIT  dgrse.com   

 

How do I fix this?
````

Comment: I have changed  dataset can any please check and suggest the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change index, not column `order`:

```py
df.index = df.index.str.replace("R_", "").str.capitalize()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         order
Preorder     4
Change       2
Delete       3
New          1
```

---

Initial `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"order": {"R_New": "1", "R_Change": "2", "R_DELETE": "3", "Preorder": "4"}}
)
```

```
         order
Preorder     4
R_Change     2
R_DELETE     3
R_New        1
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace function is designed to replace values, not the index. In your code, you're trying to change the index of the DataFrame, not the values. That's the source of the confusion.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "order": {
        "R_New": "1",
        "R_Change": "2",
        "R_DELETE": "3",
        "Preorder": "4"
    }
})

# Rename index
df = df.rename(index={
    "R_New": "New",
    "R_Change": "Change",
    "R_DELETE": "Delete",
    "Preorder": "Preorder"
})

print(df)
```